What are these Chinese characters on this metal tape measure?
I found a metal measuring tape that has lots of Chinese characters on its bottom side:

The other side has no Chinese characters:

Product label:

What is the meaning and purpose of all those Chinese characters on the tape measure? Do they have anything to do with measuring lengths?

This is a 鲁班尺 to determine 风水. Here is an introduction.
Roughly speaking, the intervals of red characters mark the preferred lengths in terms of 风水. The upper characters are for 阳宅 (the homes of the living) and the lower ones are for 阴宅 (the homes of the deceased).

魯班尺
Something to do with Feng Shui (風水)

上半部為 文公尺：用於陽宅、神位、佛具尺寸
下半部為 丁蘭尺：多用於陰宅、祖龕（祖先牌位）
紅字為吉，黑字為兇。


The upper part is the Wen Gong ruler: used for yang houses(living people's houses), altars, and Buddhist instruments. The lower part is the Ding Lan ruler: mostly used for yin houses (underworldly houses) and ancestral tablets. Red characters are auspicious, black characters are ominous.

